# Plotly Dash callback function doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am learning Dash and wanted to create a dashboard with a dropdown connected to a chart, but it doesn't work. The chart does not fill with data somehow and I get an empty dashboard with a dropdown that does nothing.

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')

app = dash.Dash()

year_options = []
for year in df['year'].unique():
    year_options.append({'label':str(year), 'value':year})


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(id='graph'),
    dcc.Dropdown(id='year picker', options=year_options,
                value=df['year'].min())
])


@app.callback(Output('graph','figure'),
            [Input('year-picker', 'value')])
def update_figure(selected_year):
    
    filtered_df = df[df['year']==selected_year]
    traces = []
    for continent_name in filtered_df['continent'].unique():
        df_by_continent = filtered_df[filtered_df['continent']==continent_name]
        traces.append(go.Scatter(
            x = df_by_continent['gdpPercap'],
            y= df_by_continent['lifeExp'],
            mode='markers',
            opacity=0.7,
            marker = {'size':15},
            name = continent_name
        ))
    return {'data':traces,'layout':go.Layout(title='My Plot', xaxis={'title':'GDP Per Cap', 'type':'log'},yaxis={'title':'Life Expectancy'})}


if __name__== '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Comment: The dropdown id is `'year picker'` but in the callback you are referencing `'year-picker'`. If you make them consistent your code should work.